# PHP Table Split By Month

Tags: php, database, mysqli

I have been trying to group the output from my database into time periods.

For example

**2013 May**

Some Data

More Data

**2013 June**

Some Data

Some Data

The code below works to an extent but will only put one row of data against each month even though there should be more. ie each month has more than one row of data

Can anyone explain why?

```
  function show_records($mysql_link)
  {
   date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
   $today=date('Y/m/d');
   $future=date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+10 months", strtotime($today)));


   $q="SELECT number,startdate,traction,tourname,start,fares,tourcompany
   FROM specials
   WHERE startdate>='$today' AND startdate<='$future' AND steam='y'
   ORDER BY startdate";


   $r=mysqli_query($mysql_link,$q);
   $lastmonth="";
   if ($r)
   {


    echo "<Table id='customers'>
    <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Locomotive</th>
    <th>Organiser</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Pick Up Points</th>
    <th>Destination</th>
    <th>Fares</th>
    </tr>";


    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($r,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
     $parts=explode('-',$row['startdate']);
     $timestamp=strtotime($row['startdate']);
     $parts2=date('YM',$timestamp);

 if (empty($lastmonth)|| $lastmonth!=$parts2) 
     {

     if (!empty($lastmonth))
     {
      echo '</table>';
 }
  echo "<h1>$parts2</h1>";
  echo "<table id='customers'>";
  $lastmonth=$parts2;               


      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$parts2."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['traction']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['tourcompany']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['tourname']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['start']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['end']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['fares']."</td>";
      echo "</tr>";

      }
     echo "</Table>";
     }

    }
   else {echo '<p>'.mysqli_error($mysql_link).'</p>' ;}
   }
   show_records($mysql_link);

   mysqli_close($mysql_link);

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the row-data only if `$lastmonth != $parts2`. Use following code instead:

```
if (empty($lastmonth) || $lastmonth != $parts2) {
    if (!empty($lastmonth)) {
        echo '</table>';
    }
    echo "<h1>$parts2</h1>";
    echo "<table>";
    $lastmonth = $parts2;
}
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>".... // and so on
```

Comment: Edited code. However it is still only showing first row for each time period

Comment: You misplaced the `}` after `$lastmonth = $parts2`

Comment: oh, and change `if (!empty) { echo '</table>'; }` into `echo '</table>'` in this situation.

Comment: Thanks Peter. That solved it. Deleted a } further down the code so it could fit in

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, the $lastmonth variable is updated only the first time. Then you're only looking for it to be "empty" which it will never be after the first update. Fix that, and I'll bet it'll work great!